# How to increase PermGen memory for eclipselink StaticWeaveAntTask

Tags: jpa, ant, eclipselink

We are using Eclipselink and need to weave the code in order for lazy fetching to work property.

During the weave process I'm getting the following error:

```
weave:  

BUILD FAILED  
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I have the following tasks within my ant build file:

```
<target name="define_weave_task" description="task definition for EclipseLink static weaving">  
   <taskdef name="eclipse_weave" classname="org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeaveAntTask"/>  
</target>  

<target name="weave" depends="compile,define_weave_task" description="weave eclipselink code into compiled classes">  
   <eclipse_weave source="${path.classes}" target="${path.classes}">  
       <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>  
   </eclipse_weave>  
</target>
```

It has been working great for a long time.  Now that the amount of code to be woven has increased I'm getting the PermGen error.  I would like to be able to up the amount of perm space.

If I was doing a compile I would be able to up the perm space via a compiler argument such as `<compilerarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=256M"/>`  but this does not appear to be a valid argument for eclipselink weaving.

How can I up the perm space for the weave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to set the max perm memory parameter in the ANT_OPTS environment variable before running ant.

`export ANT_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the Ant task "in the same JRE as Eclipse" then it's Eclipse itself that you must start up with an obese permgen.

Comment: I'm running ant from the linux shell, but you did give me a good hint, I could look at changing the defaults of the jre.